# RSA Signing with .Net and verifying with OpenSSL command

Tags: c#, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to sign a simple data with C# using Sha1 hash and RSA and then verify it with the OpenSSL command.

For my tests, I've taken the localhost certificate that is preexisting on Windows.

Here's the code used with C#:

```csharp
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sValTest = "sampledata";
    byte[] signature = Sign(sValTest, "localhost");
    string b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
    bool verified = Verify(sValTest, signature, @"pathToCer");
}

static byte[] Sign(string text, string certSubject)
{
    X509Store my = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    my.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = null;
    foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in my.Certificates)
    {
        if (cert.Subject.Contains(certSubject))
        {
            csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
            break;
        }
    }

    SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
    byte[] data = Enconding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
    byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);

    return csp.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"));
}

static bool Verify(string text, byte[] signature, string certPath)
{
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath);
    RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;

    SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
    byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);

    return csp.VerifyHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), signature);
}
```

(In that example, `verified` yields `true`)

I sent the public part of the PFX to my linux computer as well as the signature as base 64.

I then did the following:

```shell
base64 --decode sig.b64 > sig
openssl x509 -inform der -in localhost.cer  -out localhost.pem
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in localhost.pem > localhost.pub.pem
echo -n "sampledata" | openssl dgst -verify localhost.pub.pem -signature sig
```

Which ends with a `Verification Failure`.

I checked the serial number of the certificates on both sides and it matches.
Just in case, I also checked the md5 of the signature in both stations, all clear.

Any pointers on where is the obvious fail?

Comment: I'm guessing (and its just a guess) that this is using 16-bit Unicode characters: `UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding`; while this is using 8-bit clean ASCII: `echo -n "sampledata"`.

Comment: @jww I was using UTF8 in another code section, just to be sure I've tried again with ASCII, didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the hash algorithm identifier into the `openssl dgst` command, which defaults to MD5.

Your correct last line is

```
echo -n "sampledata" | openssl dgst -verify localhost.pub.pem -signature sig -sha1
```

Comment: I was absolutely sure this defaulted to sha1, should have verified 10 more times... Thank you